# cannot scroll the octave gui window 4.4

Tags: octave

I have Windows 10 and am using octave 4.4.0. I cannot scroll the command window upward, instead it is flickering and does not move. Any suggestions what would fix it?

Comment: Install GNU/Linux or Windoze 7 and try again ;-) Joke apart, windoze 10 causes many problems and it would be cool if you could help fixing them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a workaround...

1. Open cmd
2. Right click on title bar
3. Go to properties
4. Tick "Use legacy console"
5. Restart Octave GUI

Answer (score 1):

Edit > Preferences > History buffer Size (value must be 1000).
Increase the number as 2000 or greater.